# TSQL Business Rule Implementation Between Two Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a report in SSRS and at first thought I would implement these biz rules at the report level but finding it inferior to the task. So now I can either implement as custom code (vb.net) in SSRS or at TSQL level which would be my preference.

So the majority of the business rule I have already satisfied. It is this last step that has me stumped. To make it simple I have provided a sample table that represents the data I need to work with.

```
DECLARE @TeamTable TABLE
(
           TeamID VARCHAR(3),
           AssignedTask INT
)

INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('AAA', 12)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('BBB', 45)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('CCC', 67)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('DDD', 11)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('EEE', 12)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('FFF', 10)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('GGG', 11)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('HHH', 6)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('III', 3)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('JJJ', 11)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('KKK', 0)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('LLL', 4)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('MMM', 12)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('NNN', 1)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('OOO', 0)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('PPP', 12)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('QQQ', 12)
INSERT INTO @TeamTable VALUES ('RRR', 0)
```

This query get's the data in a manner that accurately represents my dataset:

```
SELECT TT.TeamID, TT.AssignedTask, RANK() OVER 
(ORDER BY TT.AssignedTask DESC) AS 'Rank'
FROM @TeamTable TT
WHERE AssignedTask > 0
```

Now here is the trick. I have to assign a weighted value to each team based upon the number of teams that have 1 or more task assigned and I don't know what to do next. So in my sample data you'll see that teams KKK, OOO, RRR have zero so 15 is our top point value and I get that using:

```
DECLARE @RankMax TINYINT
SET @RankMax = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @RankMax
```

So team CCC gets 15 points because they are top dog and it scales down.....with a twist. BBB gets 14.

AAA, EEE, MMM, PPP, QQQ all tied. So the next set of points are added then averaged and everyone gets the average score.

So 5 teams tied thus 13,12,11,10,9 are added together to equal 55 divided by 5 means each team gets 11 points.

Then we move down to JJJ, GGG, DDD another tie. 8 + 7 + 6=21 and 21/3 = 7

The rest go down to zero. So the final recordset would look like this:

```
TeamID | AssignTask | Rank |
CCC    |     67     |  15
BBB    |     45     | 14
AAA    |     12     | 11
EEE    |     12     | 11
MMM    |     12     | 11
PPP    |     12     | 11
QQQ    |     12     | 11
JJJ    |     11     | 7
GGG    |     11     | 7
DDD    |     11     | 7
FFF    |     10     | 5
HHH    |     6      | 4
LLL    |     4      | 3
III    |     3      | 2
NNN    |     1      | 1
```

Not looking for anyone to do my homework just a pointer or two in how to approach the problem would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the ranking functions. Try this:

```
with RowRank as
(
  select *
    , rownum = row_number() over (order by AssignedTask)
    , rowrank = rank() over (order by AssignedTask) 
  from TeamTable
  where AssignedTask > 0
)
select TeamID
  , AssignedTask
  , [Rank] = avg(rownum) over (partition by rowrank)
from RowRank
order by AssignedTask desc
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e75b/3).

I'm working out the ranking and the common grouping, then taking the average of the rankings in that group.

Comment: I've not seen SQL Fiddle before. That's cool. I'd give you another point for that tip if I could. Further I didn't know you could do assignment operations in the select clause like that so you have really taught me several valuable things today. Thank You!!

Comment: You're welcome! SQL Fiddle is a great resource for these sort of questions. That said, the fact you added the DDL to your question is greatly appreciated, too!